# Как работает live-стрим в YouTube?

Tags: c++, html5, streaming, online-video

Прямая трансляция пишется на диск и при этом раздаётся в браузер в реальном времени всем, кто её запросил... Как это сделано технически?

У меня система видеонаблюдения на С++ + веб. Перевёл стрим с jpeg-ов на потоковую передачу. В тестовом режиме передаёт пока только клиент серверу vp8 кадры с [.ivf](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/IVF) заголовками. Дальше серверу надо как-то обеспечить стрим этого материала в браузер по запросу и запись на диск...
Допустим, я смогу писать webm файл на диск пока идёт стрим, но как транслировать в браузер, чтобы было как в YouTube - смотришь в реальном времени... отодвинул ползунок - смотришь запись?? Ведь тег HTML5 `<video>` не будет постоянно обновлять с сервера дописываемый ежесекундно файл на диске, который может разрастись до гигабайта за день.

Как правильно организовать стрим? Что скармливать браузеру и с какими заголовками пакетов?

Comment: Это крайне широкий вопрос. По каждому из пунктов: упаковка сырого видео в webm/mkv контейнер, нарезка видео  на блоки для стриминга, упаковка видео блоков в HTTP, упаковка HTTP в TLS, организация фронтенда для приема и показа видео можно по книжке написать. А уж вариантов заголовков для скармливания браузеру вообще не счесть.

Comment: @VTT, насчёт заголовков для браузера если знаете, подскажите пожалуйста. Сервер может также работать по веб-сокетам, для исключения волокиты с HTTP. Мне главное понять какие заголовки требует `<video>` тег для отображения VP8 кадров.